# Does porn destroy dopamine receptors?

Tags: addiction

Kevin Majeres, a psychiatrist claims that porn destroys dopamine receptors. A quote from his website:

> This is why pornography causes a vicious circle. When someone views
>   pornography, he gets overstimulated by dopamine; **so his brain destroys
>   some dopamine receptors**. This makes him feel depleted, so he goes back
>   to pornography, but, having fewer dopamine receptors, this time it
>   requires more to get the same dopamine thrill; but this causes his
>   brain to destroy more receptors; so he feels an even greater need for
>   pornography to stimulate him.

Source: http://www.purityispossible.com/the-science-behind-pornography/

Answer (score 143, accepted):

No, or, at least, there is no evidence that it does.

The first problem with this is the source - obviously a site like "purityispossible.com" is going to have a moral agenda, and is going to be decidedly anti-pornography. As such, we would certainly, while not dismissing the possibility, ask that they offer research to back up their claims.

The next problem is referring to porn, love of chocolate, use of marijuana, listening to Taylor Swift songs, having sex with golf groupies (Tiger Woods' claimed addiction) as "addiction." While there might be some similar mechanisms involved in things we have trouble controlling our impulses for, the use of "addiction" as a much broader umbrella of behaviors, as opposed to the traditional "physical" addiction (body develops a physical tolerance, leading to increased dosages to achieve effect, and also leading to physical dependency and withdrawal when the substance is not available..... so the subject actually ***needing*** the substance, not just wanting or preferring) causes people to incorrectly over-equate the very different processes at work. This sets the stage for false equivalence.

In this case, here's a transcript from an online Q&A where someone asked a retired neurologist about "porn addiction" -

> Okay, well the theoretical premise proposed by this science lecturer is nothing more than the application of the well-known and studied neurological basis for drug addiction upon porn addiction which unfortunately is entirely unsupported by scientific fact with regard to the latter.

[A retired neurologists opinion | Your Brain Rebalanced](http://www.yourbrainrebalanced.com/forum/threads/a-retired-neurologists-opinion.2754/)

Furthermore, the claim that dopamine is an "addictive rewarding neurochemical" is not an accurate claim.

This article addresses the claims of dopamine behind all these different "behavior addictions," which is not accepted science, and what dopamine does and does not.  The entire article is relevant to this discussion, BTW (bold emphasis mine) -

> Dopamine serves many complex functions in the brain, and **and only kindergarten brain science describes it as an addictive drug**.
>
> Dopamine is connected to rewarding experiences, but not in that it makes you feel good....Dopamine's role here is NOT that it makes you feel good.  It doesn't - ...... Dopamine's role in pleasure and reward is it helps your brain to recognize "incentive salience".... A critical issue here is that a lack of dopamine doesn't actually make the experience feel less good.

[No, Dopamine is Not Addictive | Psychology Today](https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/women-who-stray/201701/no-dopamine-is-not-addictive)

The scientists in the field do not agree with the claims, either, when responding to papers or editorials offered in journals -

> ... Hilton and Watts offer some interesting neuroscience perspectives on their conceptualization of pornography problems as an *addictive* disorder.... Hilton and Watts offered little, if any convincing evidence to support their perspectives.... Instead, excessive liberties and misleading interpretations of neuroscience research are used to assert that excessive pornography consumption causes brain damage..... Depending on how *addiction* is defined, this is either well supported.... or whole speculative as in the case of pornography consumption.

[Neuroscience research fails to support claims that excessive pornography consumption causes brain damage | Surgical Neurology International](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3115160/)

It appears that the claims are based on false equivalence and poor, misleading interpretations of the science.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67339/discussion-on-answer-by-poloholeset-does-porn-destroy-dopamine-receptors).

Comment: While this is a very good and well-researched answer, the question doesn't actually mention the word "addiction".

Comment: @MrLister - Since it talks specifically about addiction, I'm not sure why invoking a magic word  makes a difference. The Constitution does not actually mention the word "wall of separation," or "right to a speedy trial."  If you ask someone, "what is addition," and their description matches, verbatim, the words in the question, then, yes, they did talk about addiction - "...so he goes back to pornography, but, having fewer dopamine receptors, **this time it requires more to get the same dopamine thrill;** ... this causes his brain to destroy more receptors; so he feels an even greater need.."

Comment: @MrLister - please note the subject tag.

Comment: You are right about the addictive part.  But are you claiming that excessives spikes of dopamine do not downregulate some subtype of dopamine receptors ?

Comment: @xrorox - If you remove the value word 'excessive' then I suspect yes. From my understanding of this answer, the dopamine system in the brain is involved in figuring out what it is you want to do, what's important to you. Downregulating receptors is going to cause less things to seem important to you. And if you have a broken idea of what's important, that's going to result on you focusing on more broken behavior. It seems that the seemingly simple idea of addiction is fairly complex.

Comment: @Omnifarious. Thanks. I was under the impression that the answer negated this mechanism. In this particular case I don't think we can speak of addiction. If you downregulate your receptors, you are more likely to engage in behaviors that produce higher amount of dopamine. But you are not dependant on any particular source.

Comment: @xrorox - Well, I don't know that that's the correct way to interpret this. Keep in mind as well that I'm a software engineer applying analysis that mixes together knowledge from these answers and other sources, not a trained neuroscientist by any means. But it seems like this would have the general effect of making you less interested in porn unless, for other reasons, porn was really high on your list of things to be interested in. If you look at people who have no dopamine receptors, they aren't interested in doing anything, literally. They don't even move (Parkinson's disease).

Comment: @Omnifarious - Probably not a great example, because they lose the ability to move because their nervous system can no longer control the movements (why they have the tremors and rigidity which progressively gets worse).  It's not like they have the ability to move, but no longer desire to.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet - You're right. After reading more about it. :-/ Interesting. I was thinking about the movie about L-DOPA that Robin Williams starred in. It seemed like they could move if the impetus for movement came from outside themselves. But, again, misinterpreting. Neuroscience is **hard**! :-) :-/

Comment: "Awakenings." I highly recommend the book that actual story originally came from - "The Man Who Mistook His Wife For A Hat" - by Oliver Sacks.  A ton of fascinating stories about our nervous system/brain wiring gone haywire.

Comment: Keep in mind though that the DSM does include a behavioral addiction: gambling disorder https://www.psychiatry.org/patients-families/gambling-disorder/what-is-gambling-disorder

Comment: @Fizz - yes, there has always been a designation of both psychological addiction ***and*** physical addiction.  The problem is when people start making direct, equivalent comparisons between the two very different types.  If I engage in two activities, one that creates an addiction, and one that does not, but both give the sensation of pleasure to my brain, a brain scan would show similarities between the two, because they have ***some*** similarities. The problem is when people take any expected similarity and assign greater equivalence than is warranted.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it surely does. The more accurate term for this would be the *downregulation* of dopamine receptors.  It might not be as extreme as, for instance, cocaine addiction, but watching porn does affect the brain. In fact, many drugs hijack the same reward circuits that were evolved for reproduction, that's why they are so addictive:

> The human brain is programmed to incentivize behaviors that contribute to survival.  The mesolimbic dopaminergic system rewards eating and sexuality with powerful pleasure incentives.  **Cocaine, opioids, alcohol, and other drugs subvert, or hijack, these pleasure systems, and cause the brain to think a drug high is necessary to survive.** [emphasis added]  Evidence is now strong that natural rewards such as food and sex affect the reward systems in the same way drugs affect them, thus the current interest in ‘natural addiction.’ ...

[Can Pornography Use Become An Actual Brain Addiction? (2011)](https://www.yourbrainonporn.com/2-can-porn-become-brain-addiction-donald-hilton-2011)

You can find numerous evidence that porn does cause the downregulation, but most studies do not isolate porn and instead focus on so called Internet addiction, which I think actually describe the cause of porn usage and not the Internet usage itself for the most part:

> An increasing amount of research has suggested that Internet addiction is associated with abnormalities in the dopaminergic brain system. We hypothesized that Internet addiction would be associated with reduced levels of dopaminergic receptor availability in the striatum compared with controls. To test this hypothesis, a radiolabeled ligand [C]raclopride and positron emission tomography was used to assess dopamine D2 receptor binding potential in men with and without Internet addiction. **Consistent with our prediction, individuals with Internet addiction showed reduced levels of dopamine D2 receptor availability in subdivisions of the striatum including the bilateral dorsal caudate and right putamen.**  This finding contributes to the understanding of neurobiological mechanism of Internet addiction.

[Reduced striatal dopamine D2 receptors in people with Internet addiction](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21499141)

There are more recent studies that cover porn addiction specifically:

> In a recent study by our group, we recruited healthy male participants and associated their self-reported hours spent with pornographic material with their fMRI response to sexual pictures as well as with their brain morphology (Kuhn & Gallinat, 2014). The more hours participants reported consuming pornography, the smaller the BOLD response in left putamen in response to sexual images. Moreover, we found that **more hours spent watching pornography was associated with smaller gray matter volume in the striatum, more precisely in the right caudate reaching into the ventral putamen.** [emphasis added] We speculate that the brain structural volume deficit may reflect the results of tolerance after desensitization to sexual stimuli.

[Neurobiological Basis of Hypersexuality (2016)](https://www.yourbrainonporn.com/brain-structure-and-functional-connectivity-associated-pornography-consumption-2014)

And for those who want to know more about porn addiction in general, here's the link to many studies that describe this phenomenon:

[There are no scientific studies that say porn is addictive, right?](https://www.yourbrainonporn.com/there-are-no-scientific-studies-that-say-porn-is-addictive-right)

Comment: So no permanent damage ("destroyed" dopamine receptors), but modified brain chemical levels such that uptake isn't as high, but which goes back to a proper level over time without stimulus?

Comment: While [porn addiction may be  major subcategory](http://netaddiction.com/cybersex-cyberpron/) of Internet addiction, we need to take caution about lumping them together.

Comment: The "Reduced striatal dopamine D2 receptors in people with Internet addiction" is a correlation study, not a causation study. There may be confounding factors.

Comment: @Sean Duggan, Yes. There are two main causes: less dopamine receptors and/or less dopamine availability. It usually takes 2-3 months of abstinence on average. Depending on the level of addiction, some users report that they needed up to a year to fully recover. And please note that we're talking solely about porn addiction. Masturbation without porn is fine during a "reboot", but some people prefer to temporarily cut it down in order to speed up the recovery. Sexual conditioning is another aspect that can be difficult to overcome, namely rewiring to the real deal.

Comment: I'd question the conclusions some of the sources are making and their objectivity on the matter, especially their claims about dopamines' role in the "reward' mechanism.  https://www.yourbrainonporn.com/about

Comment: People will naturally reject the existence of porn addiction if they're already wired to it and therefore have biased opinion towards it. The sources I provided are no more credible than, for instance, the Internet article presented at psychologytoday.com. I think we should consider all knowledge available to us, especially if there are no apparent conclusions on either side.

Comment: Remember folks: **We don't vote to show opinions but reward and mark good answers.** I disagree with the statements from this answer but the author is totally right there need to be both sides represented here, especially when it comes to a widely discussed topic like this. Well done! +1

Comment: @dessert We don't necessarily need both sides, especially not on this stackexchange. See for example the ["false balance"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_balance) fallacy. You will always find someone with an agenda counter to contemporary research findings.

Comment: Certainly, a source that specializes in Psychology and does not have a specific social agenda is going to be more reliable than a site of people claiming victimhood for their own woes and pushing a social agenda to forward that claim. We should consider all ***knowledge*** available, but not opinions stated without the support of science or misrepresenting what the science says, which is what they are doing on that site. If a religious site claims all women who have abortions suffer PTSD and other psychic trauma, should we accept that as valid vs actual medical science?

Comment: Consider the supposed first-hand expertise of Jenny McCarthy on vaccines and autism, and the kind of pseduo-science she claimed backed her actually supported claims. I'm not seeing a ton of difference between her and this kind of "advocacy."  BTW, I also like your snide implication that I must be dismissing the unsupported claims because I'm a porn freak. Very classy. Use of ad hominem probably doesn't help your argument much, though.

Comment: The first 4 words are gravely misleading. The question is "does it destroy receptors", to which the answer is "no", as highlighted by @SeanDuggan. Answering "Yes, of course - well, technically, almost." is very bad discourse.

Answer (score 1):

Some recent research not highlighted in the accepted answer backs it up even more, quoting [a popsci summary of if](https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/women-who-stray/201307/your-brain-porn-its-not-addictive):

> In research invited for submission to the journal Socioaffective Neuroscience of Psychology, authors Steele, Staley, Fong and Prause used EEG testing to examine the effects of visual erotica, on the brains of people who felt they had problems controlling their porn use. 52 sex addicts, including men and women, had their brain’s electrical activity examined while they looked at erotic imagery. Sex addiction theory predicts that these individuals would show brain patterns consistent with that of cocaine addicts, who demonstrate specific electrical changes in the brain’s activity, in response to drug-related cues. Sex addiction proponents, from Rob Weiss to Carnes have long argued that sex and porn are “like cocaine” in the brain.
>
> But, when EEG’s were administered to these individuals, as they viewed erotic stimuli, results were surprising, and not at all consistent with sex addiction theory. If viewing pornography actually was habituating (or desensitizing), like drugs are, then viewing pornography would have a diminished electrical response in the brain. In fact, in these results, there was no such response. Instead, the participants’ overall demonstrated increased electrical brain responses to the erotic imagery they were shown, just like the brains of “normal people” as has been shown in hundreds of studies.

So if porn is addictive, it's not in the same way as cocaine etc., at least as far as EEG measures are concerned. The actual paper is also [free in PMC](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3960022/).

The caveat to all such porn studies is that they have been surprisingly few in number.

Also [hypersexuality is more often treated](https://www.nice.org.uk/advice/esuom46/chapter/Key-points-from-the-evidence) off-label (because there are no FDA-approved drugs for it) with SSRIs, which increase serotonin, rather than with drugs acting directly on dopamine, although naltrexone (an antagonist of the opioid receptor, so at least having something to do with addiction) [has been also been tried](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4500883/). But there's not much in the way of studies of that either, and an effort to include hypersexuality in DSM-5 failed.

Perhaps the main pharmacological indicator that dopamine is somehow implicated comes from [medicated patients with Parkinson's disease](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19401861); some develop hypersexuality (and quite a few other behavioral issues like excessive gambling) as a side-effect of being treated with L-dopa, a dopamine precursor that turns into actual dopamine in the brain. However, fairly recent (2012) research indicates that at the usual therapeutic doses [L-dopa does nothing of the sort in healthy volunteers](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3251561/). Testing higher doses "will be difficult, though, since higher doses of all currently available drugs that selectively augment DA neurotransmission are limited by side effects such as nausea, vomiting, dizziness and drowsiness."

One [very recent (2017) Polish fMRI study found](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/28409565) that

> men with and without PPU [= problematic pornography use] do not differ in striatal reactivity and hedonic values either for erotic or monetary rewards. The key difference
> between these two groups is in striatal reactivity (and accompanying behavioral reactions) in response for cues.

So (amusingly) yourbrain**on**porn turned out just the same for all, yourbrain**anticipating**porn is different for some. Although this may sound reassuring, the wanting-difference part is however consistent with the [incetive salience](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2607325/) theory of addiction.

So the (addiction) question may come down to whether you think behavioral issues like gambling disorder are (or aren't) addiction. I note that the accepted answer implies that behavioral addictions aren't addictions, but this is not the prevailing opinion in the DSM-5, which [recategorized gambling disorder from an impulse control disorder to an addiction](http://blog.ncrg.org/blog/2013/05/evolving-definition-pathological-gambling-dsm-5). There's even an official blurb about this in their [change summary](https://www.psychiatry.org/File%20Library/Psychiatrists/Practice/DSM/APA_DSM_Changes_from_DSM-IV-TR_-to_DSM-5.pdf)

> An important departure from past diagnostic manuals is that the substance-related disorders chapter
> has been expanded to include gambling disorder. This change reflects the increasing and consistent
> evidence that some behaviors, such as gambling, activate the brain reward system with effects similar
> to those of drugs of abuse and that gambling disorder symptoms resemble substance use disorders to a
> certain extent.

The reason why the other proposed behavioral addictions didn't get included was the lack of enough empirical evidence in their favor as such. ([Internet gaming disorder was included in the "for future research" section](https://www.psychiatry.org/File%20Library/Psychiatrists/Practice/DSM/APA_DSM-5-Internet-Gaming-Disorder.pdf) with a passing mention that it might rise to the level of an addiction in some extreme cases.)

Anyway, here's a table with the Polish study participants' other group characteristics:

[image]

(I snipped some of the really long and boring methodological footnotes.)

One interesting (but rather obvious) fact is that more porn correlated with more masturbations. It's not at all clear what's the cause and what the effect though. Do they watch more porn because they want to masturbate more, or is it the other way around, i.e. watching more porn turns them on so they masturbate more? In other words, is PPU just the low-hanging-fruit manifestation of hypersexuality or is it really an addiction to porn? As the song goes, more research is needed.

Comment: I'd like to point out possible wrong methodology used in the first linked study. Viewing a single, or even multiple vanilla erotica images on the screen does not fully represent the actual behavioral patterns that characterize porn addicts who rather seek novelty, surprising and shocking material in order to maintain high sexual arousal for hours "with multiple tabs open", all in the privacy of their homes. **Internet** porn is clearly something new. Actually, the porn itself might not actually be the problem; it's the availability of ever novel material presented on the Internet.